# MQSeries - Any setting to allow new receiver to take over connection?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We know that MQ server could be configured such that new receiver will not be able to connect to MQ server if there is already receiver connecting to the same MQ queue. Error will look like below:

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2042' ('MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE')

But is there any way to configure server or client to allow new receiver to connect to MQ server and disconnect any existing receiver connection?

Below is currently how my receiver connects to server.  I wonder if something could be done to setIntProperty.

```
cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(mqHost);
cf.setPort(mqPort);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setQueueManager(mqQueueManager);
cf.setChannel(mqChannel);

conn = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
session = (MQQueueSession) conn.createQueueSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(mqQueue);
receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);
```

Thanks!

Gerry

Answer (score 2):

OK, you are mixing different concepts here.  Your application is using a CLNTCONN channel to connect to the QMgr's SVRCONN channel.  Yopu can have as many connections on a SVRCONN channel as memory and system resources allow.  The connection is not the problem.

The '2042' ('MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE') indicates that the program is gaining exclusive access to the queue.  There are two fixes for this:

1. Don't use exclusive access to the queue.  Check the [`DEFSOPT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp) value of the queue to see if it is set to `EXCL` or `SHARED`.  If you need it to be sharable, make sure the queue setting reflects that.
2. If you need the queue to remain exclusive (for example because messages are sequence dependent), stop the previous connection before attempting a new connection.  When a program does not close a connection gracefully, an orphaned channel agent holds the connection's queues open.  Eventually the agent times out and any exclusive input queues become available again.  If programs are leaving orphaned channels, fix the programs. As a short-term measure, you can manually stop orphaned channels to release the lock on the input queue.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks very much for the reply.  Is there any setting to allow only one connection at a time, while new connection could always take over existing connection?  Thanks, Gerry

Comment: No. The existing connection might have transactions outstanding.  An attacker might execute a denial of service by flooding the QMgr with attempts to connect to all the queues.  The list issues with this approach is long, scary and involves lots of problems with system reliability and data integrity. If an app gets exclusive use of a queue, WMQ assumes that this is because its what you wanted and will try hard to keep that connection reliable and stable until the app relinquishes it or an administrator (or monitoring agent) manually reaps the connection.